# Disable image viewing on w3m?

Tags: terminal, tmux, console, w3m

I'm using w3m in Sakura Terminal. I use tmux so only a small part of the screen should be allocated to the web browser - however, images appear all over the entire terminal window and sometimes flicker annoyingly.

I personally prefer w3m without images anyway, so does anyone know of a way to just disable this feature, or should I switch to another text based web browser?

Answer (score 1):

on w3m click o to go to options and unset :
External command to display image (by default : w3mimgdisplay)